# Serialization Java

Tags: java, serializable

Всем привет
Думал, что разобрался в сериализации, но наткнулся на непонятку. Создаю LinkedList< User >. Само собой, класс User implements Serializable. Добавляю в лист 2 юзера. Пишу весь лист в ObjectOutputStream. Потом добавляю в лист еще 5 юзеров. Снова сериализую. Дулаю flush(), все закрывается (Autocloseable).
Десериализация. читаю первый объект (ожидаю считать из файла LinkedList с 2 юзерами - так и есть. Ок. Читаю второй объект (ожидаю увидеть другой LinkedList уже с добавленными 5 юзерами). Но вижу тот же лист с 2 юзерами, что и при первом чтении.

User:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
private String name;
private int age;

public User(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", age=" + age +
            '}';
}

}
```

Main:

```
    List<User> userLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();

    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("User.ser"))) {
        userLinkedList.add(new User("Женя", 42));
        userLinkedList.add(new User("Александр", 21));

        // write whole Lists
        oos.writeObject(userLinkedList); // LinkedList

        // Add some data
        userLinkedList.add(new User("+ Александр", 21));
        userLinkedList.add(new User("+ Маша", 11));
        userLinkedList.add(new User("+ Саша", 24));
        userLinkedList.add(new User("+ Олег", 25));
        userLinkedList.add(new User("+ Оля", 27));
        System.out.println(userLinkedList);

        // now LinkedList contains 2 + 5 = 7 elements
        oos.writeObject(userLinkedList); // LinkedList

        oos.flush();
        System.out.println("Объекты сохранены");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fNFex) {
        System.out.println(fNFex);
    }

    System.out.println("Читаем объекты...");
    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("User.ser"))) {

        // read whole Lists
        List<User> u2in;
        u2in = (List) ois.readObject(); // LinkedList
        System.out.println(u2in);

        List<User> u3in;
        u3in = (List) ois.readObject(); // LinkedList with added elements
        System.out.println(u3in);

        System.out.println("Объекты восстановлены");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fNFex) {
        System.out.println("FNF Error!");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cNFex) {
        System.out.println("CNF Error!");
    }
```

---

```
Output:
[User{name='Женя', age=42}, User{name='Александр', age=21}, User{name='+ Александр', age=21}, User{name='+ Маша', age=11}, User{name='+ Саша', age=24}, User{name='+ Олег', age=25}, User{name='+ Оля', age=27}]
Объекты сохранены
Читаем объекты...
null
[User{name='Женя', age=42}, User{name='Александр', age=21}]
[User{name='Женя', age=42}, User{name='Александр', age=21}]
Объекты восстановлены
```

Что происходит? Почему не сохранился (или не прочитался) лист с добавленными юзерами?

Comment: Простите, а где вы вообще сохраняете 2 файла? Вы читаете первый объект и ожидаете 2 юзеров, а потом второй, где ожидаете 5... У вас файл всего один. В одном файле вы пишите один объект - свой лист. А то, что потом вы его читаете дважды, присваивая разным переменным, особо ситуации не меняет. Обеъкт в файле один,читает дважды одно и тоже, получаете дважды одно и тоже. В чем вопрос?

Comment: Я пишу в один файл все. Разве объекты там не хранятся последовательно? Во всяком случае, если всех юзеров писать последовательно в цикле, то потом в таком же порядке они и считываются из файла. Из ОДНОГО файла. Даже если вашей логике следовать, то записаться должен последний объект (с 2+5 элементами). Но считывается только лист с 2мя юзерами...

Comment: oos.writeObject(userLinkedList) - задумайтесь над смыслом этого вызова. вы сохраняете объект, коим является в данном случае ваша коллекция userLinkedList, которую вы и передаете в аргументах. получаете на выходе один файл с одним объектом. да, там будет несколько пользователей, ведь вы по сути сохраняете не пользователя как объект, а объект коллекции, которая содержит несколько пользователей. но коллекция сохраняется всего одна. а вы хотите сохранить в одном файле 2 коллекци, т.е. 2 объекта. так не выйдет

Comment: Как это????? А как же мне удалось в цикле слить всех юзеров, а потом их прочитать? OOS - это же стрим, т.е. поток ввода-вывода. Принцип такой же как у FileOutputStream etc...

Comment: я же не знаю, как вы их писали и читали))

Comment: for (User user : userArrayList) {
                oos.writeObject(user);
            }

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69654/discussion-between---and--).

Comment: интересная идея, а читали как?

Comment: продолжим обсуждение в чате. <- тыць

Comment: ну не суть. в цикле вы загоняете множество разных обектов. а в случае с коллекцией вы сохраняете один объект. поэтому в первом случае сохраняется все, а во втором один объект - ваша коллекция. хотите толкать в один файл - нужны разные объекты. а один и тот же объект, независимо от изменений, вы можете записать только в разные файлы.в противоном случае один файл - один объект.

Answer (score 0):

Вы по сути добавляете один и тот же объект два раза, и поэтому второй раз объект не записывается, так как он уже существует. Вместо этого я просто создал новый `LinkedList` скопировав старый и все заработало.

```
package ser;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class User implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public User(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> userLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();

        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream("User.ser"))) {
            userLinkedList.add(new User("Женя", 42));
            userLinkedList.add(new User("Александр", 21));

            // write whole Lists
            oos.writeObject(userLinkedList); // LinkedList

            // Add some data
            userLinkedList.add(new User("+ Александр", 21));
            userLinkedList.add(new User("+ Маша", 11));
            userLinkedList.add(new User("+ Саша", 24));
            userLinkedList.add(new User("+ Олег", 25));
            userLinkedList.add(new User("+ Оля", 27));
            System.out.println(userLinkedList);

            // now LinkedList contains 2 + 5 = 7 elements
            oos.writeObject(new LinkedList<>(userLinkedList)); // LinkedList
            oos.flush();
            System.out.println("Объекты сохранены");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fNFex) {
            System.out.println(fNFex);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Читаем объекты...");
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                new FileInputStream("User.ser"))) {

            // read whole Lists
            List<User> u2in;
            u2in = (List) ois.readObject(); // LinkedList
            System.out.println(u2in);

            List<User> u3in;
            u3in = (List) ois.readObject(); // LinkedList with added elements
            System.out.println(u3in);

            System.out.println("Объекты восстановлены");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fNFex) {
            System.out.println("FNF Error!");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cNFex) {
            System.out.println("CNF Error!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```